# Weird simplification of complex value and its conjugate?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Consider the following simplification

```
(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] // FullSimplify
```

> `(Sqrt[Conjugate[A]] Sign[A])/Sqrt[A]`

I am a bit confused by this output. I would have expected Mathematica to return just `1`, since

$$A=|A|e^{i(\phi+2\pi n)}~~~,~~~A^*=|A|e^{-i(\phi+2\pi n)}~~~,~~~n\in\mathbb{Z}\,,$$

obviously leads to

$$\frac{\sqrt{A}\sqrt{A^*}}{\sqrt{AA^*}}=\frac{|A|\sqrt{e^{i(\phi+2\pi n)}}\sqrt{e^{-i(\phi+2\pi n)}}}{|A|}=e^{i\frac{\phi+2\pi n}{2} -i\frac{\phi+2\pi n}{2}}=1$$

on all branches $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Instead, we get the above output, where I'm not even sure what `Sign` of a complex number is supposed to mean. What is going on? Is there a way to make Mathematica simplify this properly?

EDIT:

Just to convince everyone that there is nothing special going on for `Arg[A] >= Pi`, see the following plot

```
Plot3D[ReIm[(Sqrt[x Exp[I \[Phi]]] Sqrt[x Exp[-I \[Phi]]])/Sqrt[  x Exp[I \[Phi]] x Exp[-I \[Phi]]]], {x, 0, 50}, {\[Phi], 0, 20 \[Pi]}]
```

> [image]

Real part is always 1, imaginary part is always 0.

EDIT2:

It seems that the trouble of $\sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)}$ vs $\sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-1}$ is addressed even in the relevant [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Notes). There it is pointed out that $\sqrt{z^*}\neq \sqrt{z}^*$ when the *principal* square root function is considered. I guess Mathematica uses exactly that principal function version, which explains why it does not return what I expected.

Personally, I would have preferred if on the field of complex numbers we had non-identical $(-1)=e^{i \pi}$ and $(-1)^*=e^{-i \pi}$, which would resolve the issue and make $\sqrt{z^*}= \sqrt{z}^*$ true. But that's not standard, so I guess I can't expect it from Mathematica either.

Comment: From the "Details" section of the `Sign` documentation: "For non-zero complex numbers `z`, `Sign[z]` is defined as `z/Abs[z]`".

Comment: @JohnDoty I see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Sqrt` is a function, it *must* be defined with a branch cut (this is not a shortcoming of *Mathematica*, just a result of requiring functions to be single-valued). The cut used by *Mathematica* means that phases $\phi$ of complex arguments are moved into the interval $-\pi < \phi\le \pi$ before applying the rule $\sqrt{\exp(i \phi)} = \exp(i \phi/2)$.

In your derivation, this rule is applied without moving the argument to the correct branch. This is a misunderstanding based on the fact that in mathematics the interpretation of the symbol $\sqrt{\ldots}$ isn't as strict as in *Mathematica*. You therefore have to adjust your expectation to correspond to the meaning of `Sqrt`, or replace the function `Sqrt` by something else.

I assume you don't want to throw out `Sqrt` from the code, so here is what you could do to get the expected result:

```
Simplify[(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] /. A -> Abs[A] Exp[I ϕ], 
Assumptions -> {-π < ϕ < π}]
```

> `1`

What I did is replace `A` by its `AbsArg` representation and added the assumption about the phase `ϕ` being in the open interval excluding the boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

It evidently depends on the value of A.  Try

```
(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] // 
  PowerExpand[#, 
    Assumptions -> A \[Element] Complexes] & // FullSimplify

Piecewise[{{-1, Arg[A] >= Pi}}, 1]
```

So it's `1` if `Arg[A] <= Pi`

Comment: The `PowerExpand` function loses phase information, which is why you obtain this wrong result. See my edit for a plot, the function is equal to `1` in the lower half plane just as well as in the upper half plane.

Comment: Note that `Arg[A]` is always between `-Pi` and `Pi`, and "it's `1` if `Arg[A] <= Pi`" should read a strict `<` in place of `<=`.  Not sure why the restriction on the range of `Arg[]` is not applied in simplification.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see! That makes more sense, thank you.

Comment: If `Arg[A] == Pi`, then `A` is pure Real.  With the assumption that A is complex, `Arg[A] = Pi` is not a possibility.

Comment: If A is real and negative, `-1` is the right answer because we have `(I*Sqrt[Abs[A]])^2/Sqrt[A^2]` which is `-1`

Answer (score 1):

```
(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] /. A -> -1
(*  -1  *)
```

because it's

```
I * I / 1
```

Comment: Mathematica seems to evaluate any expression `Exp[ I Pi (1+2n) ]->-1` for any explicitly given integer `n`. However, I'm skeptical whether this is mathematically correct, since it disregards the phase. `Exp[-I \[Pi]/2]` and `Exp[I \[Pi]/2]` both square to `-1`, but are clearly different. Which means, in a proper treatment one should keep track of the branches to be able to recover them through a square root.

Comment: @Kagaratsch `Power`/`Sqrt` "give the principal value" according to the docs.

Comment: I see, so by always taking the principal value Mathematica deliberately drops the phase information. Which means, Mathematica is not applicable to properly work with complex numbers...

Comment: `Mathematica` works fine with complex numbers. It just can't read your mind about which branch of a multivalued function you want to use in a particular case.

Comment: @JohnDoty A complex `Conjugate` number is mathematically rigorously defined. And as shown in my question, when applying the correct definition of what `Conjugate` actually means the answer is the same for *all* branches $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. So I'm not sure why Mathematica would need to read anyones mind to return the only correct answer.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Say I've got a number in mind.  When it is squared, the value is `1`.  Now, the complex numbers being rigorously defined, there is only one number `1`, right?  So is `Sqrt[1]` going to give me the number I have in mind?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The argument goes slightly differently: Say you have a number in mind, call it $z$, and your number has absolute value $|z|=1$. Then complex numbers, being rigorously defined, ensure that $z\bar z=1$ and $\sqrt{z\bar z}=1$ and $\sqrt{z}\sqrt{\bar z}=1$, ragardless of what exactly your number is. Because the square root operation can not change the absolute value if it is equal to $1$, and any complex number times its conjugate is positive semidefinite. Which necessarily has to return the absolute value $1$.

Comment: What mathematica does by discarding the phase, is convert $\sqrt{e^{i\pi}}\sqrt{e^{-i\pi}}$ to $\sqrt{e^{i\pi}}\sqrt{e^{i\pi}}$ before carrying out the square root operation and multiplication. Which spoils the complex inner product and makes it not positive semidefinite, returning the value $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the answers about complex numbers, Mathematica makes no assumptions that `A` is a number.  It could just as easily be a matrix, for example:

```
In[13]:= (Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] /. A -> {{1, I}, {-I, -1}}

Out[13]= {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}

In[14]:= (Sqrt[Conjugate[A]] Sign[A])/Sqrt[A] /. A -> {{1, I}, {-I, -1}}

Out[14]= {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}
```

in which case returning a scalar would be incorrect.

Comment: I see, that is a very good point! Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: However, unfortunately, even the following does not simplify properly: `FullSimplify[(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]], 
 Assumptions -> Element[A, Complexes]]`. But was worth a shot.

Comment: Try it with `Conjugate[Sqrt[A]]` instead of `Sqrt[Conjugate[A]]`.

Comment: Ahha, then it works! Interesting curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

A bit long for a comment. Consider:

```
a = Sqrt[A] /. A -> -1
(* I *)
```

Correct. `Sqrt[-1]` is `I` by definition.

```
b = Sqrt[Conjugate[A]] /. A -> -1
(* I *)
```

Correct. `Conjugate[-1]` is `-1`, and `Sqrt[-1]` is `I` by definition.

```
c = Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] /. A -> -1
(* 1 *)
```

Correct. `Sqrt[1]` is unambiguously 1.

```
(a b)/c
(* -1 *)
```

Correct.

```
(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[Conjugate[A]])/Sqrt[A Conjugate[A]] /. A -> -1
(* -1 *)
```

Now, you consider this wrong, but it's the same as `(a b)/c`. *Mathematica* is thus consistent, which is a crucial thing to a computer algebra system. To get the answer you want, *Mathematica* would have to use a different branch cut for different instances of `Sqrt` in your expression. How is it supposed to know that this is what you intend?

Comment: My point is that for any complex number $z$ the inner product satisfies $z\bar z\geq 0$. Since $\sqrt{\bar z}=\bar{\sqrt{z}}$, the inner product $\sqrt{z}\sqrt{\bar z}\geq 0$ has to hold. $\sqrt{-1}=i$ only if $-1=e^{i\pi}$, but $\sqrt{-1}=-i$ if you write $-1=e^{-i\pi}$. When extending the field of numbers to be complex, `-1` and `OverBar[-1]` should not be identical.

Comment: That's not the usual mathematical convention, so you can hardly expect *Mathematica* to use it.

Comment: Yes, sadly it seems to be that way.